# I must design code to return an unordered set of integers in ascending and descending order in Java

Tags: java

I just started to code in Java using Eclipse. I am brand new to coding and need help trouble shooting my code. I must sort a set of integers in ascending and then descending order. Eclipse keeps giving me an error message saying "fw is never closed". What does this mean and how do I close fw?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
package square;

import java.io.*;

public class Integers 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] setOfInts = {28,3,53,4,89};
        int i, j, temp;
        FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter("sort_log.txt");
        System.out.println("Sort a set of Ints");
        
        fw.write("Unsorted set of ints\n");
        for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length; i++)
        {
            fw.write(setOfInts[i] + " ");
        }
        
        fw.write('\n');
            for (j=0; j<setOfInts.length; j++);
            {
                for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length-1-j; i++)
                { 
                    if (setOfInts[i] > setOfInts[i+1]) {
                        temp = setOfInts[i];
                        setOfInts[i] = setOfInts[i+1];
                        setOfInts[i+1] = temp;
                    }
            }
    }
    
    fw.write("Sorted set of ints\n");
    for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length; i++)
    {
        fw.write(setOfInts[i] + " ");
    }
        fw.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the JavaScript tag for? I have removed it as I don't think JavaScript has anything to do with what's being asked.

Comment: Please use intellij because is better.
And in intellij that work :

Comment: You've already close `FileWriter`. There won't be any problem. Just refresh and build the java code. The eclipse analyzer sometimes takes little time to sync the changes.

Comment: Make sure your curly brackets are aligned properly; otherwise, the code looks confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij that work for me, so ...
[image]

For you sort you can do this :

```
public class Integers
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Integer[] setOfInts = {28,3,53,4,89};
        int i, j, temp;
        FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter("sort_log.txt");
        System.out.println("Sort a set of Ints");

        fw.write("Unsorted set of ints\n");
        for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length; i++)
        {
            fw.write(setOfInts[i] + " ");
        }

        fw.write('\n');
        Arrays.sort(setOfInts);

        fw.write("asc\n");
        for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length; i++)
        {
            fw.write(setOfInts[i] + " ");
        }

        fw.write('\n');
        Arrays.sort(setOfInts, Collections.reverseOrder());

        fw.write("desc\n");
        for (i=0; i<setOfInts.length; i++)
        {
            fw.write(setOfInts[i] + " ");
        }

        fw.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

I give you an advice `Use thing that already exist`, for example here i use `Arrays.sort`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid

Comment: @aran that wasn't what he ask for. He ask why he have an error ... but i show him i don't have any error.

Comment: Using `Arrays.sort` is not the answer to an exercise on how to write a sorting algorithm.

Comment: He never said he want to create him own algo ``` I must sort a set of integers in ascending and then descending order. ```